# Passing bash variable to python command within a shell script

Tags: python, json, bash

Needing to extract two variables per line from a JSON file and use each of these 2 variables in separate follow up commands.

My script is so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

VCTRL_OUT='/tmp/workingfile.json'

old_IFS=$IFS      # save the field separator
IFS=$'\n'     # new field separator, the end of line

for line in $(cat $VCTRL_OUT)
  do
    python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load($line);print obj["ip_range"]'
  done
```

The second to last line is wrong and need to know how to do this.

The following works:

```
cat /tmp/workingfile.json | head -n +1 | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["ip_range"]';
```

But not sure how to do the same in the bash script for loop.

Comment: Single quotes in bash kill all special characters, even the `$` in `$line` variable, so instead of the variable's value, you are passing a `"$line"` string. You need to use double quotes around the `python -c ...` command.

Comment: What does the JSON file look like? There are better options than trying to run a separate Python program for every line of the file. (Ignoring the fact that JSON is not line-oriented and cannot generally *be* processed line-by-line, this is the wrong way to iterate over a file in `bash`; see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).)

Comment: @karlosss - the json.load command that runs now does not work since it is running against the json line. What needs to be modified ?

Comment: @chepner - Agreed the wrong way to iterate over a file. The contents looks like this:    {"ip_range":"1.1.1.1/24","uuid":"b4d8c9344ffb010aec2e93a78335639f","description":"string: Yellow"}
{"ip_range":"2.2.2.2/26","uuid":"b4d8c9344ffc0e0ec77893a78335639f","description":"string: Red"}

Comment: This seems rather convoluted, why the bash layer and not just write a single python script to do it?

Comment: @proycon - The entire bash script will be calling a number of application commands which are BASH based and overall it would be easier to maintain it in BASH going forward.

Comment: @chepner - Proposed answer works as shown but how can two fields be extracted from each line? For example ip_range and description

    #!/bin/bash

    VCTRL_OUT='/tmp/workingfile.json'

    parse_json () {
        python -c $'import json,fileinput\nfor line in fileinput.input(): print        json.loads(line)["ip_range"]' "$1"
    }
     while IFS= read -r ip_range; do
        echo $iprange $description >> $CONFIG_FILE
    done < <(parse_json "$VCTRL_OUT")

Comment: @dross Answer updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python wouldn't be my first choice for this kind of one-liner, but you might try

```
#!/bin/bash

VCTRL_OUT='/tmp/workingfile.json'

parse_json () {
    python -c $'import json,fileinput,operator\nfor line in fileinput.input(): print "%s %s"%operator.itemgetter("ip_range","description")(json.loads(line))' "$1"
}
while IFS= read -r ip_range description; do
   # do your thing with ip_range
done < <(parse_json "$VCTRL_OUT")
```

One alternative is to replace the Python bit with `jq`:

```
while IFS= read -r ip_range description; do
  # ...
done < <( jq -rRc 'fromjson | .ip_range+" "+.description' "$VCTRL_OUT")
```

Another alternative is to replace the entire `bash` script with Python, although that may be easier said than done, depending on what the `bash` script is actually doing.